# Does the word "egrarious" exist?

Tags: word-usage

For some reason I thought "egrarious" was a word, but I cannot find any authoritative reference to the word.

I thought it meant "ostentatiously bad".

I am aware there is a word "egregious".

Comment: Maybe I've heard this word in a song?  "_This is the dawning of the Age of Egrarious, the Age of Egrarious_..."

Comment: There's also **agrarian** ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does now that you've asked about it, but I've no idea what it means. It could indeed be a misspelling of *egregious*, which has the distinction of describing something that is remarkable in both a good sense and a bad sense.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder how many other non-existent words I have in my head?! I can only imagine it is a crossed wire in my brain or someone else had this imaginary word in their head and uttered it during my formative years.

Comment: @BenAston [At least you're not alone](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-178942.html). This is one of the ways words get added to the language, after all.

Comment: The merging of two uncommon words may play a part in the formation of "egrarious":  That one guy was egregiously gregarious, he hung out with everyone.

Answer (score 0):

***egrarious*** adj.
(egregious + gregarious)
standing out from the crowd; promiminent; conspicuous ...

...and enjoying it, letting others enjoy.

see details on [quizlet.com](http://quizlet.com/dictionary/egrarious/)

Like fantabulous; chillax; brunch.

Comment: [Link to the Quizlet entry](http://quizlet.com/dictionary/egrarious/)

Comment: The definition you give is exactly the meaning I had in my head. I presume you are saying it is a neologism. It is in no dictionary I can find.

Comment: It could have been meant as a nonce word, but stayed on. Just guessing.

Comment: Let's see if more, better answers come our way.

Comment: It looks very like a confusion between *egregious* (standing out from the crowd) and *gregarious* (enjoying being in the crowd).  Perhaps something like [this picture](http://www.funnycoolstuff.com/images/bao-xishun.jpg)

Comment: Just fusion. No confusion.