# Does the word "googling" exist?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, is-it-a-word

I wonder if the usage of *googling* is proper in the following sentence.

> I've done a bit of **googling** and review walkthroughs about this product
>   X available in the market.

I have seen this word used over the internet in some articles. Hence I have used the above line in my blog. Before publishing the post, I'd like to check out if that word exists or not. Even then, is it correct to use it?

Comment: Have you tried a dictionary?

Comment: You've seen it therefore it exists.  Whether it would be approved of in formal writing is another question.

Comment: Janus: Yes, I did and its redirecting to google word. Hence I asked.

Comment: My new favorite word for the day is "Ungoogleable".

Comment: Obviously it does, because you've quoted an example

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by “and its redirecting to google word”. If you look in a recent dictionary, you will find the word there, simple as that.

Comment: Does the word googling exist? Now it does. Darn you!

Comment: Janus : I meant to say this. Checkout this [link](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=googling+meaning&oq=googling+meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57.5802j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8). Hope its fine.

Comment: Does the word *exist* exist? Does the word *word* exist? Are those my feet?

Comment: @srk, Google is a search engine, not a dictionary. The very link you give, however, has links to a good dozen actual _dictionaries_ that all have the word in them.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Surely you mean *ungooblable*!

Comment: @tchrist [Inconceivable!](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/you-keep-using-that-word-i-do-not-think-it-means-what-you-think-it-means)

Comment: ***Ungooglable***: Germanic calque of Latin *deguglabile*, < L.  *deguglare* (*deguglo*, *deguglavi*), “to ungoogle”.

Comment: So, this was easy; it exists. However, this does raise a whole new question. Is it _googlable_ or _googleable_, _googling_ or _googleing_?

Comment: Is it inappropriate to use the word **exist** for a word? Seen a lot of questions in here, [1](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65168/does-the-word-egrarious-exist?rq=1), [2](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/129599/does-the-word-exgest-exist) and more.

Comment: It's one thing to ask "I've never seen this word, does it exist?" or "A colleague of mine used this word exactly once, does it exist elsewhere", and a different thing entirely to state "I have seen this word used all over the internet, does it exist?" Not the same thing at all. You've answered your own question, in fact before you even asked it. Not to mention that the word can actually be found in many a dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, *[google](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/google)* indeed exists as a verb.

Comment: Even "[Ungoogleable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_%28verb%29)" exists as a verb.

Comment: @Qǝuoɯᴉs, any word or sound can function as a verb in English, but ‘ungoogleable’ is primarily an adjective, not a verb.

Comment: @Qǝuoɯᴉs You’ve one *e* too many, methinks.

Comment: @tchrist methinks not :) check the link.

Comment: @Alez too much copypasta, I suppose. *Ungoogleable* is quite clearly an adjective.